# Copy to clipboard a static text?

Tags: javascript

I need to create a script that copy to clipboard's users (from any devices/OS/browser) a specific text.
I've found this library for JS [ZeroClipboard](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard). But I'am not so good in javascript, so my question is how to use this library in my script that is  more or less like this.

```
<p id="text">text to copy</p>
<button onclick="CopyToClipboard()">Copy</button>

<script>
   function CopyToClipboard(){
       What i put here?
   };
</script>
```

Help for using zeroclipboard or any other simpler way to do this?
It would be nice if it can work for most devices as possible! Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2):

I added comment to explain what's happening.

```js
function CopyToClipboard() {
  // Get the desired text to copy
  var selectText = document.getElementById('text').innerHTML;
  // Create an input
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  // Set it's value to the text to copy, the input type doesn't matter
  input.value = selectText;
  // add it to the document
  document.body.appendChild(input);
  // call select(); on input which performs a user like selection  
  input.select();
  // execute the copy command, this is why we add the input to the document
  document.execCommand("copy");
  // remove the input from the document
  document.body.removeChild(input);
}
```

```html
<p id="text">text to copy</p>
<button onclick="CopyToClipboard()">Copy</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! Does it work on iPhone? I tested but seems don't work!

Comment: You mean Safari, I wouldn't know i didn't test it.

Comment: Tested on Chrome for iPhone and Safari, not working, I'm going to open new question :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. No need to use a plugin for something as simple as you want. There is a method that lets you copy text 'execCommand("copy");'.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="This text is still being copied" style="display:none;" id="myInput">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, but i tried to hide input with style="display:none;", but when i do this it won't copy the text. can I hide the text to copy?

Comment: @RiccardoFarina I edited my answer, but as far as I can see it still outputs the text into the alert even if the input is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy static text from the `p` tag or `div` tag use below code..

```
var selectText = document.getElementById('text');
var range = document.createRange();
range.selectNode(selectText);
window.getSelection().addRange(range);
document.execCommand('Copy');
window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
```

- which means here you create the range for your text and select the node.
- After that get the selection from that range.
- Finally exec the command `Copy` and clear the ranges.

If you want to copy the text from input box use below..

```
  var selectText = document.getElementById('text');
  selectText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
```